# Ng-init if array not yet created

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a template for a application and want to display a dynamic list with names. so i got this code to show the list and add/remove rows;

```
<table ng-init="page.businessRows = []">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in page.businessRows">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.contact" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.phone" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="page.businessRows.splice($index,1)">
                Remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn" ng-click="page.businessRows.push({})">addRow</button>
```

the thing as that when this template is loaded page.busnessRows will most likely be loaded with rows so i want to change the `ng-init` to only create the empty array if businessRows is not initialised.

I have tried `ng-init="page.businessRows = page.businessRows.length < 1 ? [] : page.businessRows` but it did not work. How am i inteded to do conditions in jsangular expressions?

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
<table ng-init="page.businessRows = page.businessRows || []">
```

**Update**

I look at the parser code of AngularJS and notice that version 1.2 (currently RC) supports ternary expression.  So if you use AngularJS 1.2, this will also work (although more verbose than the above code):

```
<table ng-init="page.businessRows = page.businessRows == null ? [] : page.businessRows">
```

See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nvw5hYFjdPX49e9gK5Jt?p=preview) here.

However, your original code might not work if `page.businessRows` is `null`, because the parser will fail to dereference `length` property of `null`. So just be careful there.

Comment: This solves the problem he asked about. But I don't think it solves the larger problem of trying to use the View as the Controller.

Comment: I see your point. I, too, rarely, if ever, use ng-init. That said, I can't speak for everyone and their needs. After all, the directive is there and if somebody thinks it helps solve their problem, good for them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the ng-init will evaluate conditional statements properly. But you could refactor the condition into a controller function and call the function from ng-init.

```
<table ng-init="initializeBusinessRows(page.businessRows)">
```

The just put your conditional evaluation in the function on the controller scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

The problem is that you're allowing an action to occur before the data is loaded or ready.  A secondary problem is you're using an expression in an ng-click where a scope function or controller function should be.

So...

1. Disable that button if the form isn't ready.
2. Use your controller to *control* these interactions.

So here's an example of the controller. The $timeout was added to simulate a delayed load of data into your $scope.page variable.

```js
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $window) { 
  //Timeout to simulate the asynchronous load
  //of the page object on the $scope
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.page = {
      businessRows: []
    };
  }, 2000);


  //scope method to add a row.
  $scope.addRow = function (){
    //for safety's sake, check to see if the businessRows array is there.
    if($scope.page && angular.isArray($scope.page.businessRows)) {
      $scope.page.businessRows.push({});
    }
  };

  //scope method to remove a row
  $scope.removeRow = function(index, row) {
    if($window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) {
      $scope.page.businessRows.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

... and the HTML view (notice the ng-disabled and the ng-click) (and lack of ng-init):

```html
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in page.businessRows">
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="row.name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="row.contact" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="row.phone" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="removeRow($index, row)">
                    Remove
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn" ng-disabled="!page" ng-click="addRow()">addRow</button>
  </div>
```

Also, [here's the obligatory Plunker for you to see this in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/GbEVvdsA77j7oGEqphQA?p=preview).

Comment: ... likewise you'll probably want to have your controller set up a "removeRow(row)" method. I'll add that real quick.